# Passing txt file as an argument to a script while running

Tags: shell-script, arguments

I have a script as below

```
    for File in $(cat $IMPORT_PATH/*.txt); do
         echo `date +'%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S'` "starting $File execute" > $Import_Success_Log
        ./cli.sh -a execute -i IPROD_$File -fn formrnt -user -password>> $Import_Success_Log
         echo `date +'%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S'` "$File execute completed" >> $Import_Success_Log
    done

    ./cli.sh -authfile "$AuthFile" -a list -t area -nof > $Import_List_File


for File in $(cat $IMPORT_PATH/*.txt); do
     imp_area=`grep -iw "PRD_$File" "$IGC_Import_List_File" | grep -i prod`;

           ##Testing if imp_area variable has a value
    if [ -z "$imp_area" ]; then
       echo "- $DataBase Imp Area is not present .Please create." >> $Import_Failure_Log
     else
          Preview=`grep -iB 3 "The admin setting require" $Import_Success_Log |head -1 | awk '{print $4}'`;
      Error=`grep -i error $Import_Success_Log`;
      No_Import=`grep -i "does not exist" $Import_Success_Log`;
         if [ -z "$Preview" -a -z "$Error" -a -z "$No_Import" ];then
        echo "<li> $DataBase </li>" >> $DB_Import_Complete
     else
        echo "- $Prev is not imported as this database require a preview.  >> $Import_Failure_Log
       fi
        fi
done
```

This script checks for a txt files in a particular path and excecutes a particular command.

Now since there can be many txt files in that path so everytime i have to rename other files as to other than .txt.

For this reason i want to pass the txt file as a variable/argument to the script.

Something like below:
sh script.sh abc.txt.

Sample File Content:
File.txt

```
SQL_SEVRER_ACCOUNT
Customer_DB
Customer_support_DB
Account_DB
```

or as an argument to the crontab entry when the script is scheduled.

I am new to scripting and don't have much of an idea on this.

Comment: Where in your code snippet would you test for this file?

Comment: Couldn't get your question.
I would want to execute the script by passing the file to it.

Comment: I understand the passing part. But inside the script, where do you want to use the file? Do you want to use it where you currently use `$File`, does it replace the `$(cat $IMPORT_PATH/*.txt)` part, or something else?

Comment: yes right where i have used $File

Comment: Is your intention to let the loops iterate over the lines of the files, as you currently do, or are you actually wanting to loop over the filenames of the `$IMPORT_PATH/*.txt` files? It looks a bit odd at the moment, and you are definitely looping over the _contents_ of those files.

Comment: Yes i need to execute cli.sh for each of the databases inside the file. Also, I need to loop over the file conetent to check if it's present in application and send it to failure log in case it is not present there.

Comment: If you are new to scripting, have a look at the [Bash Beginners Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/Bash-Beginners-Guide.html) or the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/).  Or use the search engine of your choosing to sarch it for things...

Comment: @markgraf Sure . Thanks.

Comment: And do you want to pass the list of files to look inside, or the contents of these files to your script?  Or an individual entry from one of those files?

Comment: I want o pass the contents of the file to the script. It should execute for all the databases which are there in the text file.

Comment: The updated script seems to have duplicated lines. Anyway, can you focus on the stuff which is important (maybe with a sample script), there is a lot of stuff in the script which is not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated based on your updated question**

To read the databases from a file you pass as an argument you can use

```
for File in $(< "$1"); do
    echo `date +'%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S'` "starting $File execute" > $Import_Success_Log
    ./cli.sh -a execute -i IPROD_$File -fn formrnt -user -password>> $Import_Success_Log
    echo `date +'%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S'` "$File execute completed" >> $Import_Success_Log
done
```

(and similarly for all other loops)

and then call it as

```
sh your-script file.txt
```

---

Scripts can be called with arguments, those will be available in `$1`, `$2` etc. So in your case you can do

```
File="$1"
echo `date +'%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S'` "starting $File execute" > $Import_Success_Log
./cli.sh -a execute -i "IPROD_$File" -fn formrnt -user -password>> $Import_Success_Log
echo `date +'%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S'` "$File execute completed" >> $Import_Success_Log
./cli.sh -authfile "$AuthFile" -a list -t area -nof > $Import_List_File

imp_area=`grep -iw "PRD_$File" "$IGC_Import_List_File" | grep -i prod`;
```

and then call the script as

```
sh your-script filename
```

PS: This assumes that in the rest of the script (especially the part executed before your snippet) the value of `$1` isn't changed for whatever reason.

Comment: Thanks a lot . I am trying the same and will update you.

Comment: I need to execute cli.sh for each of the databases inside the file. Also, I need to loop over the file content to check if it's present in application and send it to failure log in case it is not present there. 
Updated the script in requirement.

Comment: Thanks a lot @nohillside. This worked for me pretty good.

Answer (score -1):

If you execute your script with parameters, these are automatically stored in the variables $1, $2, $3, ...

So, if you execuite your script as:

```bsh
sh script.sh abc.txt
```

then "abc.txt" is stored in variable $1

Comment: So what should be the change to my script in this case?